# Potential at the centre of two concentric shells

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

The potential of the inner shell is 10V and that of the outer shell is 5V. The potential at the centre is given in the book to be 10V. I know that inside the shell potential should be constant but how can we neglect the potential due to outer shell? In the same book I read how to calculate potential at the surfaces of concentric shells and it considered the effect due to the outer shells. Why is that?

[image: This is the question]

[image: This is the theory part of the book]

Comment: I have realized that the potential of the inner shell (10V) also accounts for the effect due to the outer shell. I thought that the given potential of inner shell was due to the charge on inner shell only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the potential looks like this:
[image: potential]
Here the potential is plotted over a 1D cross section.
The outer ring *is* adding potential to the innermost area but, since the potential at the innermost shell is given, we know that it extends to the inside as well. The inner shell is adding 5V.